# Rails: using one class in concurrent threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, concurrency

When trying to access the same class (or model) from two concurrent threads I often get `uninitialized constant $ClassOrModelName`.  Sometimes the error is not thrown, probably because the threads are not accessing the class at the exact same time. I'm not sure about that, please correct me.

How could I use the same class from two concurrent threads? Thanks!

---

Code:

```
  threads = []
  [1,2].each do |x|
    threads << Thread.new do
      p ModelName
    end
  end
  threads.each(&:join)
```

Sometimes runs successfully and sometimes I get:

```
uninitialized constant ModelName
```

Comment: you might need to show some code

Comment: @bjhaid thanks, added the code to reproduce the error.

Comment: there is nowhere in this code where ModelName was previously defined

Comment: ModelName is defined and works perfectly well if I access it from a single thread. The error is thrown only when two or more concurrent threads try to access ModelName at the same time, then it becomes an `uninitialized constant`